# psql configuration problems

Tags: ubuntu-22.04, postgresql-14

I am running postgres on Ubuntu 22.04 and whenever I run `psql -U postgres` I get the error `psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"` 
This is what my `pg_lsclusters` looks like `14  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/14/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log`

here is what the logs look like `Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 90: "local   all             postgres                                md5" 2023-06-15 12:27:47.815 PDT [37614] postgres@postgres LOG:  could not send data to client: Broken pipe 2023-06-15 12:27:50.834 PDT [37615] postgres@postgres FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres" 2023-06-15 12:27:50.834 PDT [37615] postgres@postgres DETAIL:  User "postgres" has no password assigned`
I have tried changing back and fourth between peer and md5, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Does the TCP socket yield the same issue?

Comment: Yes, it appears to be listening this is what running netstat showed tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Comment: My question was: did you try to connect over a TCP socket rather than a Unix one? For that -h flag to be set to your host, probably to the localhost.

Comment: Yes, I am configured to connect via unix socket and did try running it with the -h flag. Got the password authentication failed. Changing it to peer seems to still run me into peer authentication failed.

Comment: I did try switching it to a TCP socket too and it's telling me that `psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
`

Comment: Notice that the log message says that Unix socket is still being used, not a TCP socket.